# How can I show sections in a React page only by clicking on one section first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to create a react app that has 3 horizontal sections on the page but when you load the app only one section shows then the others get loaded if an object in one of the loaded sections is clicked. Hope this image helps explain this..
[image]
The code I plan on having looks like this

```
.....

section1(){
return(
    ..section1 stuff
)} 
section2(){
return(
    ..section2 stuff
)} 
section3(){
return(
    ..section3 stuff
)}     
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                this.section1
            </div>
            <div>
                this.section2
            </div>
            <div>
                this.section3
            </div>                        
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = { sectionOneClicked: false } 
}

section1(){
return(
    ..section1 stuff
)} 

section2(){
return(
    ..section2 stuff
)} 

section3(){
return(
    ..section3 stuff
)}

handleClick(){
  this.setState({ sectionOneClicked: true });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
                this.section1
            </div>
            {sectionOneClicked && (
              <div>
                { this.section2 }
              </div>
            )}
            {sectionOneClicked && (
              <div>
                { this.section3 }
              </div>
            )}                     
        </div>
    )
}
```

So you can handle the click using state, when the section 1 is clicked then set the state and when that is true display section 2 and section 3. If you want to hide section 2 and 3 in some case then you can again set the state to false. Also move the `onClick` to the link you will provide in section 1.

Comment: You can accept the answer which helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 0):

**Stateful Component** -> You could simply manage a state whether the sections are open or close ( boolean ).

**OnClick** -> When a section is clicked change its state to open ( or toggle based on your preferences. )

**Conditionally Render** -> Now you have state which describes if the previous sections are open or closed, you just have to conditionally render the sections. For example

```
{ section1State && <Section2 /> }
{ section1State && section2State && <Section3 /> }
```